# Installing CGAL on Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, powershell, cgal, 3d-reconstruction

I am currently following tutorials at this web link: [Link to Installation guide](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/windows.html).

In section 1.2 of this Installation guide, we are asked to run the following command:

```
./vcpkg.exe install yasm-tool:x86-windows
```

When I run this command I get the error code below:

```
Computing installation plan...
Error: yasm-tool[core] is only supported on 'native & !uwp'
```

Why is this? How can I remedy this? Thank you. I await your responses.

Comment: Is your vcpkg up to date? Does it work if you skip this step and go straight to installing cgal?

Comment: @MarcGlisse, I will try installing it without doing that step and see if it works. I will update you on the result.